# How to trigger action on embedded ContainerViewController from ViewController and how to do it inverse?

Tags: ios, swift, triggers, embed, uicontainerview

does anyone know how to pass an action from ViewController to its ContainerViewController. I try to hide the container view by an action that is triggered by itself. The ContainerViewController is embedded in the container view.

**ViewController:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var ChoseLanguageContainer: UIView!


**ContainerViewController:**

@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {

    ViewController().containerView.isHidden = true 

} //I know this does not work
```

Comment: does anyone know how to use the search box at the top for such a common question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement, I created my own delegate methods which were implemented in ContainerViewController.

```
 protocol  ContainerViewControllerDelegate :class{
        func notifyItemChange(any params you need to pass.)
    }
```

In my container ViewController, I created a variable for delegate.

```
var changeContainerDelegate :ContainerViewControllerDelegate?
```

In my parent View Controller which contains the container, I did the following.

To get the instance of view controller which is embedded in the container.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let containerViewController = segue.destination as? ContainerViewController{
             containerViewController.changeContainerDelegate = self

            }
```

Create IBOutlet of container view in your view controller.

Conform to this protocol and write the implementation in View controller.

```
func changeContainerVC(containerVCName : String ,dataToBePassed:[AnyObject]?) {
       containerView.isHidden = true
}
```

In the button action inside the ContainerViewController call the delegate like :

changeContainerDelegate?.notifyItemChange()

This works for me. Hope helps ou too!

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
ViewController().containerView.isHidden = true
```

You are making a new instance of the `ViewController` and using it to hide the `containerView`. This won't work. Instead you need to hide the `containerView` of the current instance of `ViewController`, i.e **`self`**.

Here is the code you can try:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func hideContainerView(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.containerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

**View Hierarchy:**

[image]

Let me know if you face any other issue regarding this.